# Run Axios Interceptor

Tags: vue.js, debugging, axios

Im trying to do the logs . However i follow this documentation

https://github.com/hg-pyun/axios-logger

Im getting the same result but i wanted to ask how can i run it in vuejs like the picture shown?  i only see the output in inspector in info. Kindly help how can i run this inceptor in my vuejs

[image]

Comment: Could you precise your question? I don't understand what you already have, and what you want to achieve. This logs are supposed to be in the console, isn't it?

Comment: Cause i wanted to debug the axios response log. my response already display in console log but is it possible to save that response in a file?

Comment: Still not clear to be honest. You want to save the logs in a file? There is no easy way to write files from vuejs as it's run in the browser. But from the Chrome debugger console, you can "right click > save as" to save the logs printed. Is that what you need?

Comment: sorry i just confused. is there anyway i can check the logs of axios response everyday in production?  cause i do that https://github.com/hg-pyun/axios-logger but that one is only printing in inspector. i only want to monitor and check the logs everyday but it should be store in the file right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your Vue app can only print logs to the client, thus, on each user browser's console.

If you need some kind of dashboard to aggregate all production logs, you'll have to consider adding another tool. Such tool will send via http requests all your logs to their own dashboard, which you can consult later to analyse every user's logs.

You may consider using [Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/vue/) for example.